# I am unable to trigger cordova inAppBrowser to open URLs

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

In my app I have a directive inside a repeater, and the directive displays the URLs to the users.

The code I have is the following:

```
var onDeviceReady;

onDeviceReady = function() {
  console.log("this was called");
  return window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
};
```

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

and in the html

```
<a href="#" on-click="window.open('{{data.url}}', '_blank', 'location=yes');">{{data.url}}</a>
```

When i try to open the app on the android device, the console message is printed properly (meaning that the function should be called) but all the url is not opening at all.

My index file looks like this (in case is useful):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="default-src * gap://ready file: data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; font-src 'self' data: https://fonts.gstatic.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/bower.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bower-css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style-css">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
   <ion-nav-view class="slide-left-right" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>

<script src="js/bower.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/templates.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the plugins i currently have installed are the following:

> cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
>
> cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working at the end.

Basically, I replaced

`ng-click="window.open('{{data.url}}', '_blank', 'location=yes');">`

with a function:

```
ng-click="openRUL({{data.url}})">
```

and then the function looks like this:

```
$scope.openURL = function (url){
  window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes')
}
```

and it's working perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `on-click`

You can use the html `onclick`, or the angular `ng-click` or `on-tap`, but `on-click` doesn't exist

Also, you don't need the return for the onDeviceReady, but that doesn't prevent it from working.

Comment: the return is only because I use coffeescript and i automatically converted it to js to post it here. Thanks a lot, i'll give it a go using ng-click instead! Thanks again

Comment: unfortunately, it still doesn't work.
If i use onclick, the browser opens but the url is not converted from angular to html, and if i use ng-click, the browser doesnt open at all. Ideas?

Comment: can you inspect the link in Chrome (doing remote debugging) to see if the url is converted when you use ng-click? I assume angular code is in bower.js, is that right?

Comment: yes it is converted with ng-click. Angular code is in bower.js, while my code in app.js